как с помощью Telethon отправлять сообщения в группу с топиками (каналами внутри)
понадобилось отправлять сообщение в чат, который находится в семействе, облазил весь интернет и не нашёл ничего (кроме коллеги с похожей проблемой, но без ответа)
для наглядности вот вам скриншот (для анонимности пусть будет канал яндекс игр)

в сырой код TG_api лезть не хочется, будут люди знающие как это делается?
P.S вводить айди канала с нижним подчёркиванием +топик, как это отображает ТГ - не помогает

технически, каждое сообщение в топике является реплаем на другое сообщение, начинающее топик. Вероятно, нужно слать свои сообщения тоже реплаем на сообщение начинающее топик
